# SQL Split string and append

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and only know the basics. But what I am after is a way of splitting a cell value into 2 values and add the first split value to end.

So as an example the cell value says `FB Equiv - All White`.

I want the value to result in saying `All White - FB Equiv`.

I have written this:

```
UPDATE [TABLENMAME]  
SET Colour = Colour + ' - FB Equiv'
WHERE Colour like 'FB Equiv%'

UPDATE [TABLENMAME]
SET Colour = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Colour, 11, LEN(Colour)))
WHERE Colour LIKE 'FB Equiv - %'
GO
```

This works fine, but only works on one table at a time.
Is there a way of looping through all the tables and running this?

Comment: Please tag dbms product used. (You've got som product specific SQL there...)

Comment: You need to do the same replace in several tables, I guess you rather need to re-design your table structure.

Comment: Do you mean multiple tables or multiple *values* in the same table?

Comment: Is there a table that have column 'Colour' that you do not want to edit. DBMS is needed to provide more info.

Comment: Yes there are multiple tables that have a colour column and all the colour columns need to be updated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way of looping through all the tables and running this?

Yes, by writing dynamic SQL querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES to set your UPDATE statement's table then executing the resulting SQL from memory.

But please, please don't do that. It's a really bad, risky idea with horrendous potential problems. It's also a sign there's likely an improperly normalised table design. I'd read up on normalisation and fix that design first.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap the values in a single table by doing:

```
UPDATE [TABLENMAME]  
    SET Colour = (SUBSTRING(Colour, CHARINDEX(' - ', Colour) + 3, LEN(Colour)) +
                  ' - ' +
                  LEFT(Colour, CHARINDEX(' - ', Colour))
                 )
    WHERE Colour like '% - %';
```

This is using SQL Server syntax, which seems to be the database that you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but its showing an error on the Left() function.

Comment: incorrect syntax near 'LEFT' Expecting '.',''ID,PSEUDOCOL, QUOTED_ID, orVARIABLE

Comment: @DecBro . . . The `,` should be a `+`.

Answer (score 0):

```
update [TABLENMAME]  
SET Colour = SUBSTRING(Colour, 1, CASE CHARINDEX('-', Colour) 
WHEN 0 
 THEN       
  LEN(Colour) ELSE CHARINDEX('-', Colour)-1 END) + '-' +
 SUBSTRING(Colour, CASE  CHARINDEX('-', Colour) 
 WHEN 0 
 THEN LEN(Colour)+1 
 ELSE CHARINDEX('-', Colour)+1 END, 1000)
```

WHERE Colour like 'FB Equiv%'

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All it seems to have done is take the hyphen out. So it now shows as 'FB Equiv All White' instead of 'All White - FB Equiv'

Comment: you could add "-" in between the substrings.Updated the sql

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I only want to affect the rows that contain 'FB Equiv'. It has no affect on the rows that contain 'FB Equiv' and any rows that do not contain 'FB Equiv' it has added a hyphen to the end. 'FB Equiv - All White' and 'Classic Walnut-'